# PYTHON, SyntaxError tras --> if:

Tags: python, condiciones

¿Me podrían ayudar con este código, por favor?
Se trata de un programa en que van introduciendo tareas y hay que ordenarlas
Gracias

```
    # HASTA AQUÍ HAN INTRODUCIDO LAS TAREAS Y ERRORES ESTAN SOLVENTADOS
    # AQUÍ HAY MÁS CÓDIGO....

                print("""¿Deseas mover {0} a la posición {1}?""".format(tareas[ask-1],ask))
                mover = int(input("""(Escribe el número correspondiente)
    1 - Si
    2 - No, prefiero poner {0} detrás""".format(tar))
                        if mover == 1: 
                       
                       #SyntaxError en los dos puntitos???????
                       # AQUÍ SIGO CON EL RESTO DE CONDICIONES
```

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow. Pasa el código a texto, por favor, no uses imágenes de código. Indica qué es lo que necesitas y cuál es el problema que te genera el código. Revisa cómo preguntar [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask].

Comment: No deben usarse imágenes para mostrar código. Puedes pegar el código en la pregunta y poner una línea de ``` delante y otra detrás para que salga correctamente formateado. Dicho esto, el error lo tienes en la línea anterior, en la que te falta cerrar un paréntesis. Ya tenías una pista en cómo el editor te había indentado la línea del `if`, que debería estar alineada con la línea anteiror `mover =`, pero en cambio te lo metió todo a la derecha porque "creia" que aún estabas escribiendo parte del comando `int(`

Comment: IGUALMENTE, MUCHÍSIMAS GRACIAS POR AYUDARME. Si crees que puede resultar interesante para la comunidad, entonces pongo el código a texto sin eliminar la pregunta. Mil disculpas de nuevo!

Answer (score 0):

puedes cambiar el 1 y el 2 al a, b (usando letras)?

```
# HASTA AQUÍ HAN INTRODUCIDO LAS TAREAS Y ERRORES ESTAN SOLVENTADOS
# AQUÍ HAY MÁS CÓDIGO....

            print("""¿Deseas mover {0} a la posición {1}?""".format(tareas[ask-1],ask))
            print("a. Si")
            print("b. No, prefiero poner {0} detras")
            mover = input("Respuesta: ")
            if mover == "a": 
                   
                   #SyntaxError en los dos puntitos???????
                   # AQUÍ SIGO CON EL RESTO DE CONDICIONES
            elif mover == "b":
                   # codigo si es b
            else:
                   print("Respuesta No Valida")
```

Comment: Sí, lo podría cambiar, pero entonces siempre me gusta contemplar que pueda ser mayus o minus, para cada sentencia del if, elif.

Gracias por tu recomendación